# Check The ID of an Array of Divs and Add A Class Name with the same Number

Tags: jquery

I have a list of entries like this:

```
<div id="unique-entry-id-4">
<div id="unique-entry-id-3">
<div id="unique-entry-id-2">
<div id="unique-entry-id-1">
<div id="unique-entry-id-0">
```

What I want to accomplish is this:

```
<div id="unique-entry-id-4" class="blog-entry-id-4">
<div id="unique-entry-id-3" class="blog-entry-id-3">
<div id="unique-entry-id-2" class="blog-entry-id-2">
<div id="unique-entry-id-1" class="blog-entry-id-1">
<div id="unique-entry-id-0" class="blog-entry-id-0">
```

I know that I can do something like this:

```
$("div[id^='unique-entry-id-0']").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('class', "blog-entry-id-0");
});
repeat for each div
```

But what I'd like to to is use the minimum amount jQuery to read the ID name and number and then add a class that has the same number.

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that classes should rarely be used in this fashion. A class is, by definition, a set of like elements and should be semantically named. What's their purpose here?

Comment: For the sake of confusion I did not post that each div already has class name. I just needed to be able to specify unique number that matched the id number. The ID number is created by the app that is being used and I have no control over it. The class name is what I will be able to use in a separate script to target a particular post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
$('div').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).attr('id').replace('unique', 'blog'));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ruo9u45d/)**

Comment: In the demo I added a check to the selector to only process divs with ID values. Might help with performance for this very broad selector.

Comment: Of course, OP could refine that to include a partial attribute value, as was done in the question.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it was simple and did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[id^='unique-entry-id']").each(function(i) {
        var divId = $( this ).attr( "id" );
        var spittedId = divId.split( "-" );
        var divClass = "blog-entry-id-" + spittedId[3];
        $( this ).addClass( divClass );
    });
});
```

If you are sure that the difference between "id" and "class" is only the "unique" "blog"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[id^='unique-entry-id']").each(function(i) {
        $( this ).addClass( $( this ).attr( "id" ).replace( "unuique", "blog" ) );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you div's have a parent and if their id`s are in descending order, then try this one:

```
var length=$(#parentDiv>div).length;
$(#parentDiv>div).each(function(){
var className='blog-entry-id-'+(length-$(this).index())
$(this).addClass(className);
});
```